# Single Channel LoRaWAN systematically accepts just one packet out of 3 sent by node

Tags: lorawan

I just built and tested a single channel LoRaWAN gateway which is connected to TTN as per the instructions of thing4U/esp-1ch-gateway with a single channel node both based on TTGO-ESP32Lora and eventually configured both on [www.thethingsnetwork.org](http://www.thethingsnetwork.org). Everything works nicely but I do not understand why despite the node sending data at pace of 2 minutes, the gateway receives just one packet out of three. So if I trasnmit: packets 0,3,6,9 etc. the data at ttn is updated every 6 minutes instead of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. [LoRaWAN](https://lora-alliance.org/sites/default/files/2018-04/lorawantm_specification_-v1.1.pdf) uses the first [three channels as main channels](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/lorawan/frequency-plans.html) for communication. More can be configured for use. These three exist in part because they then can always be used for OTAA.

So if you have a single channel gateway and it is listening to 868.100 MHz and your node sends on 868.300 MHz then your gateway won't hear it because it is listening on the wrong frequency.

There are several solutions:

- configure your node to only send on the single frequency your gateway is listening for.
- Add two more single channel gateways who listen on the other main frequencies.
- Add a multi channel gateway.

---

*Frequencies are only meant as an example, these frequencies are applicable to EU and may differ in your own region but the principle still stands.*

Comment: Thaks for the hint, eventually I managed the solution not setting any LMIC_setupChannel at all in the node since three basic channel are default in CFG_eu868 band then LMIC_disableChannel(1); LMIC_disableChannel(2); made the trick to force the node to use the single channel (0) configured in the gateway.

Comment: Great to hear that it helped. Please accept the answer so other people can see that this answer was helpful to your question. Upvoting is also an option